# Triple Difference (DDD) - Power Calculation Formula

Tags: statistical-power, difference-in-difference

I would like to conduct power analyses related to an experiment conducted under a triple difference estimation strategy. However, it doesn't seem like there is a lot written on this subject. Ideally, someone can point me to a closed form solution of the appropriate sample sizes needed for each treatment arm as well as post-hoc power estimates given intervention characteristics.

For further insight, the project is almost identical to the one conducted by Chetty, Looney, and Kroft (2009).

Comment: There is a paper on DID that you may find helpful: Burlig, Fiona, Louis Preonas, and Matt Woerman. 2020. “Panel data and experimental design,” Journal of Development Economics, 144, 102458.